# Removing div with no class and id without removing its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, unwrap

I am trying to remove div with no id and class `<div>` without removing its children.

```
<div class="struc">
..
..
<div class="required-field half-control form-group has-feedback">
  <label for="fxb_d56c971 class=" control-label">First Name</label>
  <input id="fxb_d56c971a class="design_textfield" type="text" value="" placeholder="First Name*">
  <div>
    <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true">
      <span id="fxb_d56c971a" class="">First Name is required.</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
..
..
</div>
```

I tried the following code which is not working

```
        var findExtraDiv = $(el).prev('label').parent();
        if ($(findExtraDiv).prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == 'div') {
            if (($(findExtraDiv).id == null) && ($(findExtraDiv).attr("class") == "")) {
                var cnt = $(findExtraDiv).contents();
                $(findExtraDiv).replaceWith(cnt);
            }
        }
```

I can find the correct div but unable to remove the parent div only

This is what I want

```
<div class="struc">
...    
  <div class="required-field half-control form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="fxb_d56c971 class=" control-label">First Name</label>
    <input id="fxb_d56c971a class=" design_textfield" type="text" value="" placeholder="First Name*">
    <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true">
      <span id="fxb_d56c971a" class="">First Name is required.</span>
    </span>
  </div>
...
</div>
```

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "without removing its children" because it contradicts the idea of removing an element.... What do you expect to happen to them ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, please:

```
$(".struc div").each(function(){
    let temp = $(this).html();
    if($(this).attr('id')===undefined){
        console.log('id is undefined');
        $(this).remove();
        $('.struc').append(temp);
    }
})
```

Here goes a working example at jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vkcds1p0/

Comment: not working for multiple empty divs. Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/3dq4nhr6/

Comment: I'm comming home and will have a look.

Comment: @OwaisAhmed the problem is you changed the name of the main div. Now I changed it to get elements of class "struc". I have updated the code and the fiddle.

Comment: When you change anything(ids, classes etc) in html you have to change the references also in jquery code

Comment: just checked here and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You code is correct except for two mistakes:

- `$(findExtraDiv).id` jQuery has no "id" property. Should be `$(findExtraDiv).attr('id') == undefined`
- `$(findExtraDiv).attr("class") == ""` missing attribute returns 'undefined', not empty string. You should have `$(findExtraDiv).attr("class") == undefined`

With these two modifications and assuming your "$(el)" is correct, your code will work.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: In that case, your findExtraDiv variable is not what you think it is. It works fine when I have the variable hardcoded to point directly to the empty div element.

Answer (score 0):

Below code can find out all div elements having no attributes and then unwrap it. This will return your requested output.

```
const noAttributeElems = $("div").filter(function(){ 
    if(this.attributes.length === 0){
        $(this).contents().unwrap();
    } 
});
```